# lucene chararrayset not found

Tags: lucene, nlp, stanford-nlp, stop-words

I am using the below solution for removing stopwords while applying stanford NLP.

https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp

This project has dependency on old version of Lucene ( 3.6.2 )

I need to migrate this code to lucene 5.5.2 in order to utilise latestfeatures of lucene.

While I try to fix the below file ,

https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp/blob/master/src/main/java/intoxicant/analytics/coreNlp/StopwordAnnotator.java

I observed that the below classes are no longer available in lucene 5.5.2

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.CharArraySet;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopAnalyzer;
```

I could not find information on the alternate classes for these from Lucene documentation.

In case if anybody is aware on the right classes to be used from the latest lucene release  , kindly revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the classes to be used from lucene 5.5.2

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopAnalyzer;
```